# Explanation of obscure Rashi (שבת דף יד)

Tags: rashi, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, maseches-shabbos, teruma

The *Bavli*, *Shabas* 13 *amud* 2, quotes a *mishna* in *Zavin* that lists some people and things that, by touching *t'ruma*, invalidate it so that it cannot be eaten. The *Bavli* says that these restrictions were rabbinic enactments. On 14 *amud* 2 it protests the inclusion of one item on that list:

> "And one who immersed that day"?? One who immersed that day [invalidates *t'ruma* by touching it not by rabbinic enactment but] by [a directive in] the *Tora* [itself], as is written "ובא השמש וטהר [=and the sun sets and he is *tahor*]"!

[*Rashi* says](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=151):

> ובא השמש וטהר. ומקמי הכא לא ואוקמינן להאי קרא בתרומה ביבמות בפ׳ הערל (ד׳ עד:) ואפי׳ לנגיעה אשכחן קרא התם כל כלי אשר יעשה מלאכה בהם במים וגו׳ והאי נגיעה היא ובעינן הערב שמש אלמא פסיל בנגיעה דאי לא פסיל למאי קרי ליה וטהר השתא מכלל דמעיקרא לא הוי טהור גמור והאי כלי לאו בר אכילה הוא ומיהו טמויי לא מטמינן דהא לאו טמא איקרי׃

In loose translation:

> "'ובא השמש וטהר'/'and the sun sets and he is *tahor*'" — but until then not.… Even for touching [*t'ruma*] we find a verse there, "כל כלי אשר יעשה מלאכה בהם במים וגו׳", which is touching and requires sunset. Thus, *t'ruma* is invalidated by touching, as, otherwise, why is it saying "וטהר", implying until then not completely *tahor*? And this *keli* is not subject to eating. But we do not say it has *tum'a*, for it is not called "טמא".

This explanation is very opaque. Specifically, the end (the last two sentences as translated) is completely obscure. What does he mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The *Maharam*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_Lublin) writes:

> ברש״י ד״ה ובא השמש וטהר וכו׳ ואפי׳ לנגיעה אשכחן קרא התם כל כלי אשר יעשה מלאכה בהם במים יובא וטמא עד הערב וטהר והאי נגיעה היא ובעינן הערב שמש וכו׳ דהאי כלי לאו בר אכילה הוא ומיהו טמויי לא מטמאינן וכו׳ כצ״ל ופסוק זה הוא בפ׳ שמיני וע״כ לענין נגיעת תרומה איירי דהא בכלי לא שייך אכילה ומדכתיב לאחר הערב שמש וטהר מכלל דקודם הערב שמש אינו טהור גמור ולמאי נפקא מינה אלא לענין שאם נוגעת הכלי בתרומה נפסלה התרומה אבל מקרא דובא השמש וטהר אינו מוכרח דאיירי בפסול תרומה בנגיעתו דדילמא הא דקאמר קרא וטהר דמשמע דעד השתא אינו טהור לגמרי היינו שאדם אוכל בתרומה קודם הערב שמש דההוא קרא באדם שהוא טבול יום אלא מדכתיב ובא השמש וטהר משמע דעד השתא לא הוי טהור גמור אבל מ״מ לא אקרי טמא ואע״ג דגבי כלי כתיב וטמא עד הערב וטהר וא״כ קראו הכתוב טמא לא עדיפי כלים מאדם והאי טמא דכתיב גבי כלי ודאי אתי לשום דרשה ודו״ק׃

That is:

[The verse "כל כלי אשר… וטמא עד הערב וטהר" (Lev. 11:32)](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0311.htm#29) is talking about a *keli* (tool, vessel, garment, or the like) that came in contact with a dead *sheretz* (small animal, let's say): the *keli* must be immersed, and, when the sun sets, the *keli* is *tahor*. The clear implication of that verse is that there's something missing in its *tahor* status before sunset; the only thing that can be wrong with a *keli* before sunset is that it can invalidate *t'ruma* by touching it. (We know it doesn't have **real** *tum'a*. Even though the verse says "וטמא עד הערב", it doesn't mean it: it doesn't say so in Lev. 22 (see below), so it can't mean it here either, as a *keli* won't have *tum'a* where a person does not; rather "וטמא" in Lev. 11 must be used for some exegesis somewhere.)

[The verse cited by the *Bavli*, "ובא השמש וטהר" (Lev. 22:7),](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0322.htm#5) is talking about someone who touched someone who touched a dead *sheretz*, not a *keli*. There, we wouldn't know it's talking about invalidating *t'ruma* by touch, as there are other reasons such a person may be called not-*tahor* before sunset. (Specifically, it could mean the man can't **eat** *t'ruma* — unlike a *keli*, which of course doesn't eat.) The verse in Lev. 11 thus sheds light on the verse in Lev. 22, telling us that it, too, is referring to a restriction on touching *t'ruma*, which is what the *Bavli* here refers to.